# Where-Object not filtering

Tags: powershell

Why isn't where-object working in this case?

```
$controlFlowArgs = @{ waitForEnter = $false }
$controlFlowArgs | Format-Table
$controlFlowArgs | Format-List
$result = $controlFlowArgs | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -eq "waitForEnter" }
$result
```

Output

```
Name         Value # Format-Table
----         -----
waitForEnter False

Name  : waitForEnter # Format-List
Value : False

# Missing result would be here
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected result? It could be just the value or both key-value pair. Also, should the input be an array of hashtables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$controlFlowArgs is a HashTable. You should probably think it differently.

```
$result = $controlFlowArgs | Where-Object { $_["waitForEnter"] }
```

would store `$false` in `$result`.
Else you can use the Hashtable directly:

```
if ($controlFlowArgs["waitForEnter"]) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where-object is working fine.  In this example, only the 'joe' hashtable appears.  Confusingly the format takes up two lines.

```
@{name='joe';address='here'},@{name='john';address='there'} | ? name -eq joe

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           joe
address                        here
```

It's still considered one thing:

```
@{name='joe';address='here'},@{name='john';address='there'} | ? name -eq joe | 
  measure-object | % count

1
```

If you want the value itself, use foreach-object (or select-object -expandproperty):

```
@{name='joe';address='here'},@{name='john';address='there'} | ? name -eq joe | 
  % name

joe
```

Usually powershell works with pscustomobjects:

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='joe';address='here'},
  [pscustomobject]@{name='john';address='there'} | ? name -eq joe

name address
---- -------
joe  here
```